# TCPClient & Sockets failing to connect to the Server

Tags: c#, .net, sockets, tcpclient

I have a very strange problem with my connection to a server on a TCPListener/TCPClient basis. At some point during testing I am unable to connect to my server-application anymore, every try it times out. Netstats on both sides show, that my application listens on the right port, and the client is trying to connect to the right ip and port, but it does not advance further than "SYN_SENT". The server just displays "LISTENING" all the time. All I can do is restart my PC, which temporarily fixes this problem. But after some connections, it starts all over again. 
Up to now I tested TCPClient and Sockets class to connect to the server but both show this behaviour, what is not surprising, as TCPClient is a wrapper around the Sockets Class afaik.

Firewall is checked on both sides, things like Remote Desktop work perfectly fine, and is not blocking the Connection of my Application. There are no connections left to close or something, already cheked everything I know (maybe not that much ;) )

So whats the problem?

Edit:

A Method that needs to connect to my Server:

```
public int GetSomeDataFromServer(string blargh)
    {
        int ret;
        try
        {
            using(ConnectionTCPStream ctp = new ConnectionTCPStream())
            {
                if(ctp.EstSecConnWithServ())
                {
                    ret = CKSHandler(ctp, blargh);
                }
                else
                { ret = (int)ErrFlags.ServerDeniedConnection; }
            }
            return ret;
        }
        catch(Exception)
        {
            InternalError = ErrFlags.ServerUnreachable;
            return (int)ErrFlags.ServerUnreachable;
        }
    }
```

The Constructor of my Class that is dealing with the Connections:

```
public ConnectionTCPStream()
    {
        Client = new TcpClient("VeryImportantAdress", 49778); //it fails right here!
        rsaCrypt = new RSACH() { RSAForeignPubKey = "An 8192-Bit long RSA Public key." };
        AESPASS = AESThenHMAC.CreatePassword(200);
    }
```

Comment: Make certain you are closing and disposing the connections when you are finished with them.

Comment: I've edited my Question. All my calls to the ConnectionTCPStream-Class are this way. In the .Dispose() i dispose the stream, than the client. So there is nothing more to do?

Comment: Update:
I Used Wireshark to see what is happening there and now i know. Nothing, literally nothing. No packages were sent somewhere, while Netstat -a -b is saying that the status of my program's connection is SYN_SENT. What is happening?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are using up all your connections or some other resource.

What do you see when you do a netstat -an ?  Do you see a bunch of open ports?

There an Article Here that could possibly help you [here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/37490/Detection-of-Half-Open-Dropped-TCP-IP-Socket-Conne)

Some other resource may be killing you, might be worth having an SA fire up a resource monitor to check the health of the host when you run into this situation.

If there's no errors being thrown, it makes your life that much harder.  The problem typically happens when you don't cleanly clean up your socket disconnects.

Comment: netstat -a shows me some connections that go directly to my computer, just a few are going somewhere else. investigating further with -b shows me that only firefox, bitdefender, and Teamviewer are connected to the internet. There is no connection open with my application.

Comment: today i hit netstat -a directly after booting my machine and i got around the same amount of connections...

Answer (score 0):

The answer is the firewall which changed its mind every now and then. I couldn't test that before because i had no access to it. Now i have changed settings while i had this blockade and it worked fine again. So the answer is: Always have access to the firewall and don't forget to check it.

Comment: That is usually the first guess, but your post said you checked it. Glad you finally tracked down the issue.

Comment: the time i posted it, i thought i still had the Windows firewall active, where i added the ports i need. But i got to know that another firewall was installed, but i had no access to it. So i had to wait until today.